# Instrumentation::callActivityOnPause does not bring app to the forefront

Tags: android, robotium

I'm using Robotium to create a test that makes sure a list view is being handled properly during onPause(). Everything looks good until trying to resume the application, as the app is never called to the forefront. Am I misunderstanding how this should work? Here's the relevant section of code:

```
mSolo.scrollDownList(5);

Instrumentation instr = getInstrumentation();
Log.d(TAG, "Calling onPause");
instr.callActivityOnPause(getActivity());

Log.d(TAG, "Calling onResume");
instr.callActivityOnResume(getActivity());

assertTrue(mSolo.scrollDownList(5));
```